# Elasticsearch doesn't except json array string provided by Kafka connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the elasticsearch sink connector to feed elasticsearch from kafka topic messages. My topic includes json array and when I post the request I'm getting that error as below. Other connectors which don't content array values are running.

elasticsearch: 7.17.13

kafka: 2.6.0

elasticsearch library file : https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch

My connector config;

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8084/connectors' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "TEST",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "connection.compression": "true",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200",
    "connection.username" :"elastic",
    "connection.password":"password",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "name": "TEST"}
  }
}'
```

Exception:

```
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:588)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Bulk request failed
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient$1.afterBulk(ElasticsearchClient.java:443)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestHandler$1.onFailure(BulkRequestHandler.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$Delegating.onFailure(ActionListener.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$RunAfterActionListener.onFailure(ActionListener.java:350)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$Delegating.onFailure(ActionListener.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$RetryHandler.onFailure(Retry.java:123)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.lambda$null$1(ElasticsearchClient.java:216)
    ... 5 more
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to execute bulk request due to 'org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes' after 6 attempt(s)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil.callWithRetries(RetryUtil.java:165)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil.callWithRetries(RetryUtil.java:119)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.callWithRetries(ElasticsearchClient.java:490)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.lambda$null$1(ElasticsearchClient.java:210)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes
        at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.CompressorFactory.compressor(CompressorFactory.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.createParser(XContentHelper.java:76)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.bulk(RequestConverters.java:226)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2167)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.bulk(RestHighLevelClient.java:620)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.lambda$null$0(ElasticsearchClient.java:212)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil.callWithRetries(RetryUtil.java:158)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the "value.converter" parameter in the config file as follows and it worked.

"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",